# Google speech recognition continuous listening and transcription at the same time

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am new to google transcription API and I have been wondering if it would be possible to continuously transcribe streaming audio similar to that of google docs.

What happens currently is that after speaking a sentence the transcription stops from there and i have to restart or press a button for the transcription to pick again.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print ('Listening')
    audio = r.listen(source)
   
 
text = r.recognize_google(r.listen(source))
print (text)
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks